Getting blank tiles when using to serve GeoTIFF files using mod_tile server
I'm stuck in one issue where I have GeoTIFF files and I want to use mod_tile but the problem is after trying everything I am still getting balnk tile in API response. I tried to generate same tile using Python and mapnik, but I am able to do so.
I am adding all information here
mapnik.xml
<Style name="raster-style"> </Style> raster-style gdal /usr/share/renderd/mod_tile_poc/AQ.tif true /usr/share/renderd/mod_tile_poc/mapnik.log debug
/etc/renderd.conf
[renderd]
pid_file=/run/renderd/renderd.pid
socketname=/run/renderd/renderd.sock
stats_file=/run/renderd/renderd.stats
tile_dir=/var/cache/renderd/tiles

[mapnik]
font_dir=/usr/share/fonts
font_dir_recurse=0
plugins_dir=/usr/lib/mapnik/3.0/input

[default]
URI=/osm_tiles/
TILEDIR=/var/lib/mod_tile
XML=/usr/share/renderd/example-map/mapnik.xml
HOST=0.0.0.0
TILESIZE=256

[example-map]
URI=/tiles/renderd-example
XML=/usr/share/renderd/example-map/mapnik.xml

This is info about geotiff file:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: AQ.tiff
Size is 7220, 2810
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
CS[ellipsoidal,2],
AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
ORDER[1],
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
ORDER[2],
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-180.500000000000000,84.099607528087063)
Pixel Size = (0.050000000000000,-0.050000000000000)
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left (-180.5000000, 84.0996075) (180d30' 0.00"W, 84d 5'58.59"N)
Lower Left (-180.5000000, -56.4003925) (180d30' 0.00"W, 56d24' 1.41"S)
Upper Right ( 180.5000000, 84.0996075) (180d30' 0.00"E, 84d 5'58.59"N)
Lower Right ( 180.5000000, -56.4003925) (180d30' 0.00"E, 56d24' 1.41"S)
Center ( 0.0000000, 13.8496075) ( 0d 0' 0.01"E, 13d50'58.59"N)
Band 1 Block=7220x1 Type=Int32, ColorInterp=Gray
NoData Value=-255

